# Публикация приложения в C#

Tags: c#, установка, clickonce

Есть проект на C# в Visual Studio 2017.

В свойствах проекта, во вкладке Публикация нажимаю опубликовать проект (Опубликовать сейчас), и появляются файлы в т.ч. setup.exe.

Пробовал установить это же приложение через данный setup, а он почему то даже не спрашивает куда разместить файлы, и заливает всё сюда

`C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ECNPP8CQ.PPD\19TMXRON.YYL\news..tion_62b27be5d82208a6_0001.0000_f30126141a371c42`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы в setup.exe при установке можно было указать папку размещения файлов? Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Все правильно, VisualStudio использует технологию ClickOnce при публикации десктопных приложений. Если вы хотите полностью настраиваемый инсталятор, придется искать что-то другое, вариантов достаточно, на вкус и цвет, советовать не буду, мне ClickOnce нравится

Comment: Мне было необходимо добиться автообновления для моей программы, и с помощью ClickOnce это удалось осуществить)) Но setup'ник совсем негодный) Может быть все таки посоветуете что-нибудь?

Comment: увы, ClickOnce не позволяет настраивать расположение файлов. В принципе, вы можете сами сделать "обновлятор" для вашей программы, который будет проверять наличие обновлений и т.д., но "из коробки" это реализовано только в ClickOnce, насколько лично мне известно

Comment: нашел неплохую статью [Автоматическое обновление программ на C#](https://habrahabr.ru/post/217325/). Код местами спорный, но сама идея раскрыта раскрыта хорошо, а код можно и переписать. С таким обновлением можно использовать любой инсталятор.

Comment: Спасибо) Уже читал ее, вот сейчас думаю как лучше поступить

Comment: Позже могу оформить ответ нормально, или сами напишите, когда выберете решение. В вопрос, думаю, стоит добавить информацию о необходимости поддержки авто-обновления, может что-то еще найдется.

Comment: Попробуйте [http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php](InnoSetup) и настройте его на работу с папкой Release вашего приложения. Можете собрать как кастомный инсталлятор, так и использовать собственные скрипты, коих в сети достаточно.

Comment: Что не так с моей ссылкой?)